# Show a complete graph with n vertices, the weight of a MST is less than or equal to the min weight of cycle that passes through all vertices

Tags: algorithm, graph, proof, vertices, hamiltonian-cycle

I am really struggling with this proof and would really appreciate a detailed explanation:

Show a complete graph with n vertices, the weight of a MST is less than or equal to the min weight of cycle that passes through all vertices (also called a hamiltonian cycle)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As each vertex is connected to all others, all permutations of nodes can constitute a valid Hamiltonian cycle. Among the possible Hamiltonian cycles of the complete graph, let's pick the one with the least cost.

For an N-node graph, assume that permutation P of the nodes v<sub>1</sub>v<sub>2</sub>...v<sub>N</sub> and set of edges E as defined below constitute the Hamiltonian cycle with the least cost.
    E={(v<sub>1</sub>, v<sub>2</sub>), (v<sub>2</sub>, v<sub>3</sub>), ..., (v<sub>(N-1)</sub>, v<sub>N</sub>), (v<sub>N</sub>, v<sub>1</sub>)}

Let's prove the questioned lemma by contradiction.

Assume there exists an MST T with the sum of weights greater than the sum of the cost of all edges in E. Let's name that sum of costs as c<sub>E</sub>. If that was the case, there would exist another tree T' such that sum of its edge costs is c<sub>E</sub> - c<sub>(v<sub>i</sub>, v<sub>(i+1)</sub>)</sub>. Basically we could cut the edge between v<sub>N</sub> and v<sub>1</sub> and consider the rest of the least-cost Hamiltonian cycle as a tree. As long as the edge (v<sub>N</sub>, v<sub>1</sub>) had a non-negative cost, c<sub>E</sub> - c<sub>(v<sub>i</sub>, v<sub>(i+1)</sub>)</sub> would be less than or equal to the cost of T, cost of which was higher than c<sub>E</sub>. Therefore, there exists a conflict and our assumption as to the existence of such an MST T must have been incorrect.

Note that the proof above would be valid regardless of which edge you cut, as long as it has a non-negative cost.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose the weight of the minimum spanning tree is greater than a Hamiltonian Cycle, choose any edge in the cycle and remove it, it will become a new spanning tree (covers all the vertices) that has a less weight than the minimum spanning tree, hence the contradiction.